# Registering compatability PageRenderer in Maui causes stack overflow exception

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm trying to reuse an existing PageRenderer I had from Xamarin.Forms

project, in its migrated app form.

I get a stack overflow exception when a page starts to load:

> 0x39 in Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_void_method_a  C#
> 0x74 in Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12320,4    C#
> 0x2D in Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualVoidMethod at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:93,6    C#
> 0x69 in Android.Views.ViewGroup.Layout at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net7.0/android-33/mcw/Android.Views.ViewGroup.cs:3369,5   C#
> 0xD4 in Microsoft.Maui.ViewHandlerExtensions.PlatformArrangeHandler at D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ViewHandlerExtensions.Android.cs:133,4  C#
> 0x2 in Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler<Microsoft.Maui.IView,Android.Views.View>.PlatformArrange at D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.Android.cs:15,4 C#
> 0x37 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.RendererToHandlerShim.PlatformArrange at D:\a_work\1\s\src\Compatibility\Core\src\RendererToHandlerShim.Android.cs:51,4  C#
> 0x1F in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ContentPage.ArrangeOverride at D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\ContentPage.Impl.cs:22,4    C#
> 0x2 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IView.Arrange at D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\VisualElement\VisualElement.Impl.cs:111,4 C#
> 0x4F in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android.PageRenderer.OnLayout at D:\a_work\1\s\src\Compatibility\Core\src\Android\Renderers\PageRenderer.cs:169,4   C#
> 0x10 in Microsoft.Maui.MauiViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII at D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\obj\Release\net7.0-android\generated\src\Microsoft.Maui.MauiViewGroup.cs:206,4 C#
> 0x11 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPZIIII_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:429,5   C#

I tried to comment the renderer's code, doesn't help:

```
    using Android.Content;
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform;
    using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
    using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android;
    using PetActivityMobile.Core;
    using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;

    namespace PetActivityMobile.Droid.Renderers
    {
    public class CreateAccountViewRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        private bool _initialized;
        private Page _page;

        public CreateAccountViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            if (!_initialized && e?.NewElement != null)
            {
                _initialized = true;
                _page = e.NewElement;

                //The appearing event invoke before OnElementChanged called.
                //So I'm changing the keyboard behavior also here for the first time when page up.
                App.Current.On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan);

                _page.Appearing -= OnAppearing;
                _page.Appearing += OnAppearing;
                _page.Disappearing -= OnDisappearing;
                _page.Disappearing += OnDisappearing;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
        {
            _page.Appearing -= OnAppearing;
            _page.Disappearing -= OnDisappearing;
            _initialized = false;
        }

        private void OnAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan);
        }

        private void OnDisappearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
        }
    }
}
```

I include it in my Android project like so:

```
private void RegisterRenderers(MauiAppBuilder mauiApp)
{
    mauiApp.ConfigureMauiHandlers((handlers) =>
    {
        handlers.AddCompatibilityRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyRenderer));
        handlers.AddCompatibilityRenderer(typeof(CreateAccountView), typeof(CreateAccountViewRenderer));
    });
}
```

The Entry's renderer works fine.

Did anyone also try to reuse page renderer from xamarin.forms in maui?

Answer (score 0):

Since `PageRenderer` is obsolete on Maui, you can try to use the corresponding handler/mapper.

You can refer to the following Handler ：

```
public class ContentPageHandler : Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PageHandler
{
    protected override void ConnectHandler(Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView nativeView)
    {
        base.ConnectHandler(nativeView);
        ContentPage.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    protected override void DisconnectHandler(Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView nativeView)
    {
        ContentPage.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        base.DisconnectHandler(nativeView);
    }

    ContentPage ContentPage => VirtualView as ContentPage;

    void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e) => ConfigureInteractivePopGesture();

    void ConfigureInteractivePopGesture()
    {
        if (this is IPlatformViewHandler handler && handler.ViewController?.ParentViewController?.NavigationController is UIKit.UINavigationController navControler)
        {
            navControler.NavigationBarHidden = true;
            navControler.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Delegate = new GestureRecognizerDelegate();
            navControler.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}

public class GestureRecognizerDelegate : Foundation.NSObject, UIKit.IUIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{

}
```

And register it in `MauiProgram.cs` :

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        return MauiApp.CreateBuilder()
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
#if IOS
            .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
            {
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(ContentPageHandler));
            })
#endif
            .Build();
    }
```

**Note:**

1.There is a known issue about this, you can check it here: [PageRenderer compatibility not rendering page content](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7174).

2.For more information,please check document: [Migrate a Xamarin.Forms custom renderer to a .NET MAUI handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/dotnet/maui/migration/renderer-to-handler?view=net-maui-8.0)

Comment: Microsoft said that all previous Xamarin.Forms renderers will be supported in Maui.
I'm just trying to use them now, I don't want to rewrite it. The issue you mentioned is from 2 years ago(!) and is not resolved or provide workaround that work for all cases. If that is not enough, I now encounter another issue where: App.Current.On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan); worked on XF, but does not work on maui. There's just too many issues with maui at this point, and its in GA...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. For the new issue on Maui you mentioned above, you can create a new issue on [Maui of GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues). :)